# Resize image using PHP if it's too small

Tags: php, image, gdlib

I'm allowing user uploads, and I want to scale their images up if they're too small (low quality is a non-issue). I need to make the smallest side become 150px and have the other dimension scale up to keep the aspect ratio. I need to make it work for .jpg, .gif and .png files.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, I'm struggling to find anything about making images larger like this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [dynamically scale images in php jpg/png/gif](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248149/dynamically-scale-images-in-php-jpg-png-gif)

Comment: PHP docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php Lots of examples there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Alexander for the WideImage suggestion.

I simply used this:

```
require_once('WideImage/WideImage.php');
$image = WideImage::load($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$resized = $image->resize(150,150,'outside','up');
$resized->saveToFile($target_file);
```

It worked perfectly, and by using the "up" option, it only scales images smaller than the dimensions set up, and leaves everything else.

Answer (score 3):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248149/dynamically-scale-images-in-php-jpg-png-gif/1248256#1248256), give it a try to [WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks alot, will look into it now.

Comment: This would have been better posted as a comment to the question.